# How can I pass an env var arg to maven down to a shell script?

Tags: maven

I'm using the exec plugin to call a shell script from maven and want to pass an arg to my maven command that will get forwarded to the shell script. So if I do

```
mvn exec:exec compile -Dfoo=bar
```

I'd like to be able to access foo in my shell script with `$foo`. I've tried passing it as a parameter to the shell script from the pom.xml using `${env.foo}` and `${foo}`, but I always just end up with those exact literals in the shell script instead of "bar", which foo should expand too.

My pom.xml is like

```
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <groupId>asdf</groupId>
      <version>1</version>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <id>asdf</id>
          <phase>compile</phase>
          <goals>
            <goal>exec</goal>
          </goals>
        </execution>
      </executions>
      <configuration>
        <executable>bash</executable>
        <commandlineArgs>myscript.sh ${env.foo}</commandlineArgs>
      </configuration>
     </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `arguments` or `commandlineArgs` configurations.

The key point is that you must provide a value for `foo` either:

- On the command line: `-Dfoo=bar`
- By defining a property: `<properties><foo>bar</foo></properties>`

For example:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <executable>bash</executable>
        <arguments>
            <argument>myscript.sh</argument> 
            <argument>${foo}</argument>
        </arguments>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Then running ...

```
mvn exec:exec -Dfoo=bar
```

... will result in `myscript.sh` being run with one argument: `foo`.

Note: the plugin configuration in your question looks incorrect. Specifically; the `groupId` ("asdf") and the `version` (1).